# Android webview, evaluateJavascript and get values as Array

Tags: javascript, java, android, android-webview

I am trying to get javascript results using webView.evaluateJavascript method. I can get the return value as type of string. When i changed the variable type from String to String[], it automatically generates this line of code

> (ValueCallback)  new ValueCallback<String[]>().

```
   public void getDataFromJs(String command, WebView webView) {


    webView.evaluateJavascript("(function() {" + command + "; })();", (ValueCallback<String>)  new ValueCallback<String[]>() {
        @Override
        public void onReceiveValue(String[] s) {

            MyList=s.clone();
            
        }

    });
```

> error: incompatible types: <anonymous ValueCallback<String[]>> cannot be converted to ValueCallback

Answer (score 0):

I think you must change the signature like this :

`webView.evaluateJavascript("(function() {" + command + "; })();", (ValueCallback<String[]>)  new ValueCallback<String[]>() {}`

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not work but thanks for the answer.